# Connect to gmail using hwi / oauth-bundle

Tags: symfony, gmail, hwioauthbundle

I'm using hwi-oauth bundle to login with accounts of social networks, but I'm having a problem with login to gmail, when I am already connected to the networks, should go straight to the first screen of the system, and this happens when connect the facebook. But when I connect Gmail, it always asks to allow the application, not just the first time. Anyone know why gmail always asks permission? This is a setting on my system, or in gmail account?

Comment: are you using fos userbundle? if so check this gist


https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

Comment: I am not usign FOSUserBundle.

Comment: is this problem about session?

Comment: I do not believe that is the session. After all this is a treatment that gmail supposed to do, so that when you log on facebook to managerial their palicativos, you can take the x permission, there when you log in with facebook application it asks you x permission again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `approval_prompt` parameter to `auto` in your resource owner configuration. The default value should be `force`.

Example:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: main
    resource_owners:
        google:
            type:            google
            client_id:       xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client_secret:   vX6qyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxI6Qn7
            scope:           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
            options: 
                approval_prompt: auto
```

Comment: Unrecognized option "approval_prompt" under "hwi_oauth.resource_owners.google"

Comment: Sorry forgot the options key